# Fill one Table with information from another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 Tables with the following fields:

Table_1:

```
Date,       Month,   Dayname
2013-01-01, January, Tuesday
```

This goes from 2013-01-01 to 2013-12-31

Table_2:

```
Workers_ID, Monday, Monday_Hours, Tuesday, Tuesday_Hours and so forth
1,          TRUE,        8,         TRUE,         8       ...
2,          False,       0,         FALSE,        4
```

What i need is a Table:

```
Date, Month, Dayname, Hours_to_work, Workers_ID
```

This Table has `Number of workers` x `Days a year` rows and in each row you can see how many hours a specific worker works.

My problem, i have no clue how to accomplish that. It would be greate if someone could help me with it.

Comment: Look into examples for the sql 'unpivot' function for table 2 in order to get the columns {Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday...} and {Monday_Hours, Tuesday_Hours,...} into rows. That should be enough to get you started and we can help where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ian P gives good advice as far as revising your schema.

If you're absolutely stuck with the current design, here's a strategy you could use:

```
SELECT Date, Month, Dayname, Workers_ID,
  CASE Dayname
    WHEN 'Monday' THEN Monday_Hours
    WHEN 'Tuesday' Then Tuesday_Hours
   -- etc...
  END AS Hours_to_work
FROM Table_1 CROSS JOIN Table_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few things here, but its all part of the learning curve! First, there are functions within MS SQL to provide Month an Dayname, look up DateName and DatePart so if you havnt already, these should be calculated columns on a DateTime or smallDate column. Second, Table_2 is a not an ideal design, in general, tables should be narrow, indexes wide. So Table2 should be of the form WorkersID, Date, Hours and may well have a covering index, or at worst a composite clustered index on Date, EmployeeID. It is then (relatively) easy to produce well perfoming Queries on your data.

If you maintain your structure I would also say a pivot would not help you, I think you want a union against date and employeeId if you maintain your structure. MS SQL also now contains functionality to produce a sequence of values in a range (contiguous range of dates)  http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: I did it as Ian said and rebuild my table and it works. Still great to know the 'unpivot' function and to completely understand the cross join now. Thanks everybody!